# Error showing image on jdialog form

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a JDialog called from a JFrame. This Jdialog load some data passed from the jframe.I can load all data ok except an image. I´m passign this image in a String in which I have the path, and load it using a method (cargarImagen()).

This is the code of the JDialog:

```
public class ContactoMantenimiento extends JDialog {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6291928431785031824L;

ContactoJDBCImpl cc= new ContactoJDBCImpl();

private Contacto c;
private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField txId;
private JTextField txNombre;
private JTextField txApellido1;
private JTextField txApellido2;
private JTextField txTelefono;
private JTextField txDireccion;
private JTextField txCp;
private JTextField txCiudad;
private JTextField txEmail;
private JTextField txFecha;
private JLabel     lblImagen;
private JTextField txFoto;
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ContactoMantenimiento dialog = new ContactoMantenimiento();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public ContactoMantenimiento() {

    setModal(true);

    setBounds(100, 100, 588, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new FormLayout(new ColumnSpec[] {
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                ColumnSpec.decode("default:grow"),
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.GROWING_BUTTON_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_COLSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_COLSPEC,},
            new RowSpec[] {
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                RowSpec.decode("6dlu"),
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,
                FormSpecs.RELATED_GAP_ROWSPEC,
                FormSpecs.DEFAULT_ROWSPEC,}));
        {
            JLabel lblId = new JLabel("Id");
            panel.add(lblId, "4, 4, right, default");
        }
        {
            txId = new JTextField();
            txId.setEditable(false);
            panel.add(txId, "6, 4, fill, default");
            txId.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblDireccin = new JLabel("Dirección");
            panel.add(lblDireccin, "8, 4, right, default");
        }
        {
            txDireccion = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txDireccion, "10, 4, fill, default");
            txDireccion.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            lblImagen = new JLabel("");
            panel.add(lblImagen, "14, 4, 1, 7");
        }
        {
            JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Nombre");
            panel.add(lblNombre, "4, 6, right, default");
        }
        {
            txNombre = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txNombre, "6, 6, fill, default");
            txNombre.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblCdigoPostal = new JLabel("Código postal");
            panel.add(lblCdigoPostal, "8, 6, right, default");
        }
        {
            txCp = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txCp, "10, 6, fill, default");
            txCp.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblPrimerApellido = new JLabel("Primer apellido");
            panel.add(lblPrimerApellido, "4, 8, right, default");
        }
        {
            txApellido1 = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txApellido1, "6, 8, fill, default");
            txApellido1.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblCiudad = new JLabel("Ciudad");
            panel.add(lblCiudad, "8, 8, right, default");
        }
        {
            txCiudad = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txCiudad, "10, 8, fill, default");
            txCiudad.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblSegundoApellido = new JLabel("Segundo apellido");
            panel.add(lblSegundoApellido, "4, 10, right, default");
        }
        {
            txApellido2 = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txApellido2, "6, 10, fill, default");
            txApellido2.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblTelfono = new JLabel("Teléfono");
            panel.add(lblTelfono, "8, 10, right, default");
        }
        {
            txTelefono = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txTelefono, "10, 10, fill, default");
            txTelefono.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblFechaNacimiento = new JLabel("Fecha nacimiento");
            panel.add(lblFechaNacimiento, "4, 12, right, default");
        }
        {
            txFecha = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txFecha, "6, 12, fill, top");
            txFecha.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email");
            panel.add(lblEmail, "8, 12, right, default");

        }
        {
            txEmail = new JTextField();
            panel.add(txEmail, "10, 12, fill, default");
            txEmail.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            txFoto = new JTextField();
            txFoto.setEditable(true);
            panel.add(txFoto, "14, 14, fill, top");
            txFoto.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            JButton btnCambiar = new JButton("Cambiar imagen");
            btnCambiar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    String path = buscarImagen();
                    cargarImagen(path);

                }
            });
            panel.add(btnCambiar, "14, 12");
        }

    }
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            JButton btAceptar = new JButton("Aceptar");
            btAceptar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    Boolean correcto = false;
                    String id= txId.getText();
                    Contacto c = new Contacto();
                    Date fecha=null;
                    fecha = parseFecha (txFecha.getText());

                    if (txId.getText().length()>0){
                        c.setIdContacto(Integer.parseInt(txId.getText()));
                    }
                    c.setNombre(txNombre.getText());
                    c.setApellido1(txApellido1.getText());
                    c.setApellido2(txApellido2.getText());
                    c.setDireccion(txDireccion.getText());
                    c.setCp(txCp.getText());
                    c.setCiudad(txCiudad.getText());
                    c.setEmail(txEmail.getText());                                      
                    c.setFechaNacimiento(fecha);
                    c.setTelefono(txTelefono.getText());                                                
                    c.setFoto(txFoto.getText());

                    if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                        correcto = cc.insertarContacto(c);

                    }else{

                        correcto = cc.actualizarContacto(c);

                    }
                    if (!correcto){

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "Error al actualizar la base de datos" );

                    }else{

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getParent(), "Base de datos actualizada" );
                    }
                    dispose();

                }
            });
            btAceptar.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(btAceptar);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btAceptar);
        }
        {
            JButton btCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar");
            btCancelar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            btCancelar.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(btCancelar);
        }
    }


}

public Contacto getContacto(){

    return this.c;

}

public void setContacto (Contacto c){

    this.c= c;

}
/*
 * 
 * Método que convierte un string en una fecha con el formato requerido
 */
public Date parseFecha(String fecha){

    Date fechaDate = null;
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    try {
        fechaDate = formato.parse(fecha);

    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return fechaDate;
}
/**
 * Método que carga los datos al inicio
 */
public  void cargarDatos(Contacto cs){

    //Rellenamos los datos del formulario

    txId.setText(Integer.toString(cs.getIdContacto()));
    txNombre.setText(cs.getNombre());
    txApellido1.setText(cs.getApellido1());
    txApellido2.setText(cs.getApellido2());
    txTelefono.setText(cs.getTelefono());
    txDireccion.setText(cs.getDireccion());
    txCp.setText(cs.getCp());
    txCiudad.setText(cs.getCiudad());
    txEmail.setText(cs.getEmail());
    txFecha.setText(formatearFecha(cs.getFechaNacimiento()));
    txFoto.setText(cs.getFoto());

    //Mostramos la imagen
    cargarImagen(txFoto.getText());

}

String formatearFecha (Date fecha){
    String ff;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ff=sdf.format(fecha);

    return ff;
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public String buscarImagen(){

    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filtroImagen=new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG, PNG & GIF","jpg","png","gif");
    jfc.setFileFilter(filtroImagen);
    int opcion = jfc.showOpenDialog(getParent());
    String path="";

    //Si pulsamos en aceptar
    if (opcion==jfc.APPROVE_OPTION){

        path = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();         


    }return path;
}

public void cargarImagen(String path){

    //txFoto.setText(path);
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(path);
    Icon icono = new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblImagen.getWidth(), lblImagen.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    lblImagen.setIcon(icono);

}
```

And this is the error code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero
at java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.pcastelbon.interfaces.ContactoMantenimiento.cargarImagen(ContactoMantenimiento.java:384)
at com.pcastelbon.interfaces.ContactoMantenimiento.cargarDatos(ContactoMantenimiento.java:350)
```

UPDATE:

```
ContactoMantenimiento cmantenimiento = new ContactoMantenimiento();
                       c.setFechaNacimiento(cmantenimiento.parseFecha(txFecha.getText()));          
                cmantenimiento.setTitle("Modificar [ "+c.getNombre()+" "+c.getApellido1()+" ]");
                cmantenimiento.setContacto(c);
                cmantenimiento.cargarDatos(c);
                cmantenimiento.setVisible(true);                    


                //Actualizar tabla
                cargarTabla();
```

I think that the problem is that I am calling cargarDatos(), which load the data (included the image), before the setvisible(true). But I can´t put it after because my jdialog is modal.
Any idea??

Comment: Please see edit to answer. Consider in the future posting comments to **all** folks who answer your question, if you want our input regarding your question edits.

Comment: Also for your problem consider posting images (or links to *images* if you currently don't have enough rep) of your desired JDialog layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what is wrong:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) must be non-zero

I'm guessing that it's this line that's tripping the exception:

```
new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblImagen.getWidth(), 
       lblImagen.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

Understand that your JLabel has width and height of 0 and likely has not been *rendered* at the time that `cargarImagen(...)` method is first called. I would avoid basing the size of the image on the label's current width or height at creation time, and also would avoid setting sizes as much as possible. If you need more help, create and post a valid [minimal example program](http://sscce.org), a much smaller piece of code that is a complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, and that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

---

> But I can´t put it after because my jdialog is modal. Any idea??

Yes, again, don't base the size of the icons on the size of the JLabel. Again, please consider posting code that we can relate to, that we can actually run, a minimal code example that demonstrates your problem, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). This will allow us to run your code and modify it and perhaps even correct it.  Please read the link before replying as it supplies many important details on the SSCCE requirements. You've posted way too much code, most of it completely unrelated to the problem at hand, and much of it, including non-core Java layouts, and images we don't have, that prevent us from compiling and running your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your image can't be found by the system, and so you get an empty ImageIcon and then a IllegalArgumentException when trying to resize that empty image at `cargarImagen`.

Try this to check if the requested image exists:

```
public ImageIcon checkImagePath(String path) {
    URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might result in a NullPointerException, but shouldn't cause the exception that the original poster is currently seeing.

Comment: Thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels. You are ofcourse correct I've updated my answer.

Comment: I´ve updated with some info. I think I-ve allocated the problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem setting the size of the icon by myself. The problem was I was getting the size of the jLabel before the constructor finish.

Here was the problem:

```
new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblImagen.getWidth(), 
   lblImagen.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

And that´s how I solved it:

```
 new ImageIcon(ii.getImage().getScaledInstance(150,200, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
```

I think there is a better way to solve this, so I will keep on trying.

Thank you very much.